How to properly print user input in the correct position in 32-bit assembly?
I am currently developing a simple "About me" section in the terminal. I am using NASM assembly and running Ubuntu in Oracle VM. I am currently having trouble with printing the user input together with the label.
The desired output should be label:userinput but what happens is only the ascii-art and the label follow the correct cursor position but the user input is either scattered or not next to the label.
Here's my assembly code so far:
section .data
    clearScreen db 27, '[2J', 0          ; ANSI code to clear screen
    asciiArt1 db 27, '[5;4H', "   _   _                 _                    ", 10, \
              27, '[6;4H', "  /_\ | |__   ___  _   _| |_   _ __ ___   ___ ", 10, \
              27, '[7;4H', " //_\\| '_ \ / _ \| | | | __| | '_ ` _ \ / _ \", 10, \
              27, '[8;4H', "/  _  \ |_) | (_) | |_| | |_  | | | | | |  __/", 10, \
              27, '[9;4H', "\_/ \_/_.__/ \___/ \__,_|\__| |_| |_| |_|\___|", 10, 0

    cursorNameLabel db 27, '[8;65H'      ; Adjusted position for the name label
    nameLabel db 'Name: ', 0
    
    cursorEmailLabel db 27, '[12;4H'    ; Adjusted position for the email label
    emailLabel db 'Email: ', 0

    cursorBottom db 27, '[40;1H'

section .bss
    name resb 20     ; Reserve 20 bytes for the name
    email resb 25    ; Reserve 25 bytes for the email

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    call clearTheScreen
    call userInputs
    call displayAsciiArt
    call displayInfo
    call exitProgram

clearTheScreen:
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, clearScreen
    mov edx, 4
    int 0x80
    ret

userInputs:
    ; Input for name
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, nameLabel
    mov edx, 6          ; Length for the name label
    int 0x80

    mov eax, 3
    mov ebx, 0
    mov ecx, name
    mov edx, 20          ; Max length for the name
    int 0x80

    ; Input for email
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, emailLabel
    mov edx, 8          
    int 0x80

    mov eax, 3
    mov ebx, 0
    mov ecx, email
    mov edx, 25          ; Max length for the email
    int 0x80
    ret

displayAsciiArt:
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, asciiArt1
    mov edx, 300         ; Total length of ASCII art
    int 0x80
    ret

displayInput:
    ; Input parameters: 
    ; ecx = label address, edx = buffer address, ebx = cursor position
    mov eax, 4          ; sys_write
    mov ebx, 1          ; file descriptor (stdout)

    ; Move cursor
    mov ecx, [esp + 4]   ; Load cursor position from stack
    mov edx, 32          ; Length for cursor
    int 0x80            ; Write cursor position

    ; Print label
    mov ecx, [esp + 8]   ; Load the label address
    mov edx, 32          ; Length of the label
    int 0x80            ; Write label

    ; Print input
    mov ecx, [esp + 12]  ; Load the input address
    mov edx, 20         ; Display name input length (or change to 25 for email)
    int 0x80            ; Write input
    ret

displayInfo:
    ; Display Name
    push cursorNameLabel ; Push cursor position for name
    push nameLabel       ; Push name label
    push name            ; Push name address
    call displayInput    ; Call displayInput
    add esp, 12         ; Clean up stack

    ; Display Email
    push cursorEmailLabel; Push cursor position for email
    push emailLabel      ; Push email label
    push email           ; Push email address
    call displayInput    ; Call displayInput
    add esp, 12         ; Clean up stack
    ret

exitProgram:
    ; Move cursor to the bottom before exiting
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, cursorBottom
    mov edx, 7
    int 0x80

    mov eax, 1
    int 0x80


The output looks like this:
Terminal
My code before is longer and I decided to make it short so it's readable.
I have more things to print out and I am testing out with 2 user inputs first.
I just need the ascii-art, label and user input to print accordingly.

Your displayInput uses 32 for length.


cursorNameLabel db 27, '[8;65H'
nameLabel db 'Name: ', 0
cursorEmailLabel db 27, '[12;4H'
emailLabel db 'Email: ', 0


There seems to be a lot of confusion about the length of these messages in your program! eg. For the printing of nameLabel you're using 6 (omitting that terminating zero), but for the printing of emailLabel you're using 8 (including that terminating zero). The sys_write expects a length anyway, so better not mention that terminating zero at all.
The first error is that because in displayInput you have used 32 as the length for both cursorNameLabel and nameLabel, inevitably you will be printing much more than what you expect, and with disastrous results.
But there's a second error too. You don't respect the order that the arguments got placed on the stack!

push cursorNameLabel ; Push cursor position for name
push nameLabel       ; Push name label
push name            ; Push name address
call displayInput    ; Call displayInput
add  esp, 12         ; Clean up stack


Based on these instructions, displayInput will find cursorNameLabel at [esp+12], nameLabel at [esp+8], and name at [esp+4].
And even a third error is present because although the system call will preserve EBX, you should not trust EAX to have retained its value! So reload EAX with 4 each time. In fact, all of the general purpose registers are preserved with the exception of EAX that will contain the result (error code or other). See https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Interfacing_with_Linux.

Now what about those small differences between the lengths for 'name' and 'email'? Why not make your code robust and unify those lengths so they are the same and you can succesfully execute displayInput twice? So, give 'name' also a buffer of 25 bytes just like 'email', and prepend a space character to " name: " so it becomes just as long as "email: ". This would also be nicer to look at...

displayInput:
    mov ebx, 1          ; file descriptor (stdout)

    mov ecx, [esp + 12] ; Load cursor position from stack
    mov edx, 7          ; Use identical lengths
    mov eax, 4          ; sys_write
    int 0x80

    mov ecx, [esp + 8]  ; Load the label address
    mov edx, 7          ; Use identical lengths
    mov eax, 4          ; sys_write
    int 0x80

    mov ecx, [esp + 4]  ; Load the input address
    mov edx, 25         ; Use identical lengths
    mov eax, 4          ; sys_write
    int 0x80
    ret


The messages follow each other in memory (they are adjacent), so there's no reason to output the messages separately. You can combine their outputs:
    cursorNameLabel  db 27, '[8;65H'
    nameLabel        db ' Name: '
    cursorEmailLabel db 27, '[12;4H'
    emailLabel       db 'Email: '

    ...

    name             resb 25
    email            resb 25

    ...

    push cursorNameLabel  ; Push cursor position for name
    push name             ; Push name address
    call displayInput     ; Call displayInput
    add  esp, 8           ; Clean up stack
    push cursorEmailLabel ; Push cursor position for email
    push Email            ; Push email address
    call displayInput     ; Call displayInput
    add  esp, 8           ; Clean up stack

    ...

displayInput:
    mov ebx, 1          ; file descriptor (stdout)

    mov ecx, [esp + 8]  ; Load cursor position AND label (from .DATA)
    mov edx, 7+7        ; Use identical lengths
    mov eax, 4          ; sys_write
    int 0x80

    mov ecx, [esp + 4]  ; Load input address (from .BSS)
    mov edx, 25         ; Use identical lengths
    mov eax, 4          ; sys_write
    int 0x80
    ret


you should not trust EAX to have retained its value! - EAX is the return value for all system calls, so it's not just a "maybe" or chance of happening to work.  (Unless the return value of the previous system call happens to be the call number you want for the next, like after a write with length 4.)
